# Send A varriable from controller to blade

Tags: laravel

> how can i inject a variable from controller to blade ,it is header
>   blade so it common for every page but no route url or controller
>   function is connected with it, please tell me a way to send the data
>   from Controller To header.blade.php Is there any possible way to
>   inject the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can share data with all views using your `AppServiceProvider` located in your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`
In the `boot()` method, use the `view()` helper and assign data.

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider 
{
    public function boot() 
    {
        view()->share('name', 'My Name');
    }
}
```

You can use it like any other variable in your view like this :

```
{{ $name }}
```