# How to pass variables master layout blade in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8, but don't seem to know which controller controls the layout master blade file. I have been able to pass variables to the sub-view (Profile page) file successfully but don't know how to achieve that with the layout view master blade.

I am trying to pass variables from a controller called `ProfileController` in `app\Http\Controllers` to the master blade layout. In the profile controller, I have a code that retrieves user profile data from the database.

```
$profileInfo = Profile::with('address')->where('id', '=', '1')->get();
return view('admin_pages.profile', compact('profileInfo'));
```

In the profiles table, I have names and image fields `first_name, last_name, photo` which I can access with a foreach loop from the data `$profileInfo` passed to the sub-view using

```
@foreach($profileInfo as $data)
{{ $data->first_name}}
@endforeach
```

and so on.

My master blade file is located at `resources\views\layout\admin.blade.php`. I want to be able to display the `names` and `photo` from the `admin.blade.php` so the logged in user can see their profile image when logged in even when they don't visit their profile page (sub-view) which is located at `resources\views\admin_pages\profile.blade.php`, extending the master blade (`admin.blade.php`).

Please kindly help out.

Comment: Master blade files are just invoked by the `extends` directive which in turn is being invoked by the view returned by the controller.Also, do post the exact code you want to be accessed. Else, simply use the `isset` in the master file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61942614/4575350

Comment: I have updated question with the exact codes requested @SachinBahukhandi

Comment: you "could" use a view composer

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
You can pass variable from the blade file via the @extends as second argument function.

Controller:

```
public function index(){
$title='Sir/Madam';
return view('home',compact('title'));
}
```

Home.blade.php

```
  <?php
    @extends('layouts.admin', ['title' => $title])
```

Layout.master.blade.php

```
dd($title)
```

you will see results.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to learn about Laravel Component.

You can make the `profile` in `admin` layout with dynamic data, reusable without pass variable in every controller and route.

Create an Admin component with artisan:

```
php artisan make:component Profile
```

It will create a `Profile.php` as component controller and `profile.blade.php`

Open Profile.php and add this code:

```
public function render()
    {
        return view('components.profile', [
            'profile' => Profile::with('address')->where('id', '=', '1')->first();
        ]);
    }
```

Open profile.blade.php

```
<div>
  {{$profile->first_name}}
</div>
```

Now, render the Profile component on your template admin.

Replace

```
@foreach($profileInfo as $data)
{{ $data->first_name}}
@endforeach
```

with

```
<x-profile/>
```

You can learn more by reading blade documentation in this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#components)